# Can't seem to deploy because of package loading problem

Tags: django, deployment, web-deployment, pythonanywhere

I am unable to deploy my app on pythonanywhere because of the following error when I try to migrate my databases.

The app installs and works on local, but when I try run in pythonanywhere bash shell to build the dbs:

```
 `./manage.py migrate`
```

I get the following error. I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
 app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
    File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/new_app-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
   module = import_module(entry)
   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/new_app-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_tables2'
```

Please help, any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the package inside the virutalenv?

Comment: did you upload you requirements.txt file via `pip freeze > requirements.txt` before pushing?